# Edge Browser missing bookmarks after relogin

Tags: browser, bookmarks, microsoft-edge

I am using the edge browser for some time now and had many bookmarks/favorites saved. Last week I have noticed that the Edge icon had a little briefcase besides it and I did wonder where this came from and I noticed that there was also a profile icon in the top left on the browser.

I clicked it and saw that I was logged in with my company microsoft account and I just clicked logged out.

After that the browser appears to have made a full reset. Browser history gone, bookmarks gone, dark mode disabled and sites where I was logged in are also logged out.

So I did login again with the same microsoft account but the browser was still in the default settings... I tryed to press the synchronise button on the profile but it just says that this is not possible..

Is there any chance that I can get back all the bookmarks I have lost?

Comment: [You accidentally launched an Edge Business profile](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2023/08/22/microsoft-edge-for-business-now-available/). If you performed a Reset, it’s not clear if you did that, then your original profile was wiped.

Comment: A small hope is to check for bookmarks/favourites in the file `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks`. Look also inside the Recycle Bin.